# Combine Two Data Set CSV Files in Python

Tags: python, nlp, data-science

I have 2 datasets and each has 2 columns namely code, description. I want to read both the files search for similar text and map the codes of dataset 1 and dataset 2 together. For example.

file1.csv

```
code, description
111, Milk producer
112, IT specialist
```

file2.csv

```
code, description
001, Milkman
002, Driver
```

Now the combined dataset would be,
file_combined.csv

```
code1, description1, code2, description2
111,milk producer,001,milk man
112,IT specialist,002,drvier
```

Comment: please when you put pieces of code or dataframe highlight the parts and with ctrl + k you manage to format the text. Edit the question so it's more understandable.

Comment: Is this a one-time thing? In that case, you can use excel or google sheets

Comment: We can do data merge part by pandas easily. But could you clarify more on : `search for similar text and map the codes of dataset 1 and dataset 2 together`

Comment: actually, I want to merge files on basis of the same contextual meanings...

Comment: From what i understand, contextual meaning here is defined by the similarity in description column. So after loading data you can find out the `cosine_similarity` between two dataframe for `description` column. You can merge dataframes above some threshold say 0.75 and above. Cosine similarity : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.read_csv('path/to/file1.csv')
d2 = pd.read_csv('path/to/file2.csv')
d1.rename(columns={'code':'code1', 'description': 'description1'}, inplace=True)
d2.rename(columns={'code':'code2', 'description': 'description2'}, inplace=True)
new_df = pd.concat([d1, d2], axis=1)
new_df.to_csv('path/to/new_file.csv', index=False)
```

This does not solve the part of **search for similar text and map the codes of dataset 1 and dataset 2 together** . Please clarify more and we can solve it.